# DocuSign API - Request Payments via Stripe - Use Stripe Test Account

Tags: stripe-payments, docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign Sandbox environment to test out sending agreements and request [payment](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/payment/) using the Stripe payment Gateway. I've added Stripe as a Payment Gateway and can add a new Payment tab to a template successfully.

I just wanted to make sure, before I send an actual envelope, how do I confirm that it will also be using the Stripe test/sandbox environment and not the live Stripe account to collect payment here? I wouldn't want to accidentally request money into my live Stripe account during testing.

Comment: You should probably ask Docusign support about this one; it's a pretty niche question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use any stripe account and just use the 4242 fake credit card numbers to do your testing.

[Here is more information about testing from Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/testing)